# .Net SerialPort receive overrun on relatively small packets

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am attempting to replace a C library used for communications to a device over RS-485. My code works well on some serial devices and all USB-to-RS485 and IP-to-RS485 devices that I have tried. However, on other serial devices, it fails to correctly receive packets that are longer than about 28 bytes. After about that many bytes, it receives some garbage characters and times out (as it never receives enough characters).

On the same hardware, I can receive data through the C library without issue. (So, the hardware is clearly capable).

Initially, I was calling SerialPort.BaseStream to get a stream and then Stream.ReadByte on the stream to receive the data. I found an offhand reference in the documentation indicating that BaseStream is not buffered. So, I switched to calling SerialPort.ReadByte - which made no difference.

In an attempt to be more efficient, I switched the code to call SerialPort.Read for larger chunks of data. This (counter-intuitively) made things worse - failing after the 20th character.

As SerialPort.ReadBufferSize defaults to 4096 bytes (and won't even accept anything smaller) I am confused as to how the packets can overrun at 20-ish bytes.

How does one go about receiving data on a serial port such that the read buffer comes into play?